How to fix "upstream prematurely closed" error of nginx with SSL?

This is actually not a duplicated question. Please read.

I'm trying to connect my subdomain (node-ssl.example.com) to my ubuntu server to obtain a secure SSL websocket connection (wss://node-ssl.example.con)
So i have configured my simplest nodejs websocket application with Nginx and SSL (issued by letsencrypt via certbot).
Whenever i try to open a connection to my app, i get a 502 error. Since i have configured access_log and error_log directives for nginx, here is the log of those files:
# /var/log/nginx/domains/node-ssl/access:

xx.xxx.xx.xx - - [06/Jun/2024:02:40:07 +0330] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 166 "-" "Apidog/1.0.0 (https://apidog.com)"

# /var/log/nginx/domains/node-ssl/error:

2024/06/06 02:40:07 [error] 30289#30289: *37 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xxx.xx.xx, server: node-ssl.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:6007/", host: "node-ssl.example.com"

My certificate is available at this location:

fullchain: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
key: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

My Nginx configuration:
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  if ($host = www.example.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
  if ($host = example.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
  return 404;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name node-ssl.example.com;
  
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

  error_log /var/log/nginx/domains/node-ssl/error;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/domains/node-ssl/access;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6007;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    proxy_send_timeout 86400;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}

My nodejs program:
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const app = express();
const server = https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem'),
  keepAliveTimeout: 6000000
}, app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  console.log('A client connected.');

  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('Received:', message);
    ws.send(`Your message was: ${message}`);
  });
});

server.listen(6007, function() {
  console.log('WebSocket server listening on port 6007');
});


systemctl service (for when i was trying to run my program with systemctl):
# /etc/systemd/system/node-ssl.service
[Unit]
Description=WebSocket Server

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.3/bin/node /var/www/example.com/jws/index.js
Restart=always
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/example.com/jws/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

supervisor service (for when i was trying to run my program with supervisor instead of systemctl):
# /etc/supervisor/conf.d
[program:jws]
directory=/var/www/example.com/jws/
command=/home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.3/bin/node /var/www/example.com/jws/index.js
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/nginx/domains/jws/err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/nginx/domains/jws/out.log

More details:

My server configuration:

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Mem: 8G
CPUs: 2


I have generated my certificate with this command:


sudo certbot --nginx -d example.com -d www.example.com


I have opened the port 6007 with ufw command:

sudo ufw allow 6007

What i tried so far:

It's actually about 5 days im struggling with it, searching the web and asking AIs


As you see in the logs, I used APIDog to establish the connection. But i also tried to use wscat, piehost, new WebSocket(...)

In my nodejs program, i also tried to pass the second parameter to fs.readFileSync as utf8.

In my nodejs program, i used console.log to log the result of fs.readFileSync methods, Both are reading the .pem files correctly.

My nodejs program is now running on port 6007. But i also tried from 6001 to 6008

I also have a laravel websocket application, I get the same result from that as well.

I also tried to configure nginx to proxy requests from a subdirectory (wss://example.com/ws) instead of wss://node-ssl.example.com subdomain.

I also used Supervisor instead of a systemctl service.

I tried to start my application with root user using node index.js command.


I can confirm these:

The 6007 port is open (sudo ufw allow 6007)
My certificate is not expired (It's working on other subdomains, and the main domain)
My CDN provider is not proxying requests
If i remove SSL specific configurations from Nginx config and my nodejs program, the program works correctly without any issue. (I could access to my ssl-freed program with ws://node-ssl.example.com)
The program is correctly running (tested with systemctl and supervisor)

